# Buffering line in ArcMap is creating smaller buffer than expected?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, distance, buffer

When I buffer a point (red dot on image) by 3 miles, it is 3 miles on all sides. When I buffer a line (blue line on image) by 3 miles, it is more like 2.67 miles on the sides parallel to the line. I tried various projections, but I basically get the same result.

Any ideas on why this happens or workarounds?

[image]

Comment: What coordinate system is your point/line data in? If it is lat/long this may be the cause, try projecting your data into a coordinate system in meters then do the buffer?

Comment: Which projections did you try; were they all geographic?  How did you create the buffers (which tool, settings)? Any geoprocessing environment settings? It's possible to create planar or geodesic buffers depending on your methods. See the help http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//000800000019000000 along with the How It Works link at the top of that page.

Comment: Which ArcGIS version?

Comment: Version 10.0. Sounds like 10.1 has some different options but sadly still in 10.0.

Comment: Line and point files were in Nad27. Tried map in Nad27, Albers Equal Area US, and State Plane. Now that I think of it all the buffers did create in Nad27 regardless of map projection. I'll try projecting the line file like someone had suggested. I'll take any other suggestions. Thanks all!

Comment: At 10, buffering lines is still Cartesian only. I would have expected state plane to be closer to "truth". Possibly do a custom azimuthal equidistant, centered at the data. Or try Buffer Wizard, and set it for feature-optimized.

Comment: Are you doing this through the Geoprocessing tool or during an edit?  In any event, I think more precise details of your steps will need to be edited into your question for us to be able to reproduce it without guessing.

Comment: Just to put closure on this, I made the line into state plane. Made the map projection the same state plane and then buffered. 3 miles all around!! Thank you all!

Answer (score 2):

When buffering (among other distance related operations) in a *geographic* coordinate system, your result may appear or be distorted in 2D because geographic is on a sphere/ellipsoid, not flat. Geographic uses angular degrees for measurement, and a degree of longitude can vary significantly in terms of distance depending on latitude (which is *relatively* consistent). So what appears as a circle near the equator would be a very squashed ellipse near the poles - see [Tissot's indicatrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tissot's_indicatrix).

If you are in a *projected* coordinate system (like a State Plane zone), that spherical/3D surface has been flattened out, with some distortion, to a 2D plane. Therefore when you create your buffer, the results should be much more consistent in terms of distance - though possibly inaccurate over large distances. The Esri article [Understanding Geodesic Buffering](http://www.esri.com/news/arcuser/0111/geodesic.html) give some detailed explanation.

It sounds like you may have been running into an issue with either the original data coordinate system being geographic, on-the-fly reprojection not being set up correctly, or the buffer using the original CRS (as geographic) and not the dataframe (as projected). Note also that if two CRS or projections have different datums, you also need to specify a correct transformation for the dataframe to use (there are other questions here on that subject).

Related:

- [Correct use of buffering by field (distance) in ArcGIS for Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130423/)
- [How does ArcMap buffer linear features?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133294/)